# What is RemoteSystemsTempFiles in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I noticed that I had a project named RemoteSystemTempFiles which I never have created. After googling it seems to be plugin feature on eclipse, but didn't got any other idea of it.

Can any one please give me a better idea, of what could I have done and bit explanation on this folder? and also if its not harmful to my other projects!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can delete it if you wish, it doesn't do any harm to other projects.
It is created by the remote systems explorer that comes with eclipse.

Comment: You can find Eclipse Remote Systems config in Window -> Preferences -> enter remote systems in search box on top

Comment: Does anyone know which eclipse setting will turn this off completely? I don't want RemoteSystemsTempFiles to be recreated every time I use eclipse.

Comment: For me, the project is not shown in my workspace, but I still get errors about its missing after I deleted the files from my file system.  Anyone know why Eclipse still thinks I have this project in my workspace?

Comment: [To turn it off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627463/what-is-remotesystemstempfiles-in-eclipse#7972543).

Comment: @user880772: Turning it off, did not work for me, but un-hiding the RSE files in the project explorer view and deleting them there (despite the fact, that on the file system they were already gone), did the trick for me. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16675296/1947205

Answer (score 96):

If you want to remove the RemoteSystemsTempFiles, just go under Window -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown and uncheck "RSE UI". Then you can remove the folder and eclipse won't recreate it.

Comment: For this to work for me, I had to delete the project and contents on disk _from within Eclipse using the Project View_. It wasn't good enough to delete the folder from disk directly.

Answer (score 57):

In `Window->preferences` type **'remote'**. Click on remote systems view and uncheck the box that says **'reopen remote systems view to previous state'**.

Eclipse already adds the **.metadata** folder - why does it add extra clutter?

Comment: FYI, This appeared for the first time in my workspace just after Eclipse requested (and I confirmed) the upload of user data that it does from time to time in order to improve Eclipse.  I'm running Indigo.

Answer (score 16):

If you're still seeing unwanted results in **RemoteSystemsTempFiles** when searching for a resource (e.g. CTRL+SHIFT+R), you can manually show the Eclipse resource in the Project Explorer and remove it...

Project Explorer view > Customize View... > Filters > Uncheck "RSE Internal Projects" > OK > find it in the Project Explorer tree > expand it > remove old folders.

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling with this folder for some time now, since NO solution I've tested so far worked..

Fortunately, today I found the solution that solves this issue:

from eclipse\plugins folder remove all the (org.eclipse.rse.*.jar) files (or backup them for your confort).

This are the ones responsable for the creation of this folder.

Eclipse works perfectly without them (I do not use any functionality from those packages).

Enjoy!

Comment: I can understand your concern, but the solution really solve the issue. I've tested it on both Eclipse Juno and Eclipse Kepler and works like a charm. Just remove (backup) the org.eclipse.rse from features and plugins folder, and RemoteSystemsTempFiles is GONE, without any side effects noticed. This setup is used daily by more than 6 people in our team.

Comment: That's great, but what happens when those libraries are needed? Eclipse crashes, potentially corrupting code, ruining projects, etc.

Comment: Now there are 13 people in my team using Eclipse Kepler with the above trick. It never crashed, and never corrupted any code or ruined a project. Not sure where/how those jars are used, but it looks like we never accessed/used a functionality that relied on those jars.

Comment: Works for me. It may be corrupting eclipse, but from my perspective eclipse corrupted my setup and did not give me an obvious option to turn their "feature" off.

Comment: Eclipse is made up of a bunch of plugins. Removing some plugins doesn't necessarily break it. Eclipse comes with a lot of garbage. In fact I run this for both Eclipse Java and CDT: http://pastebin.com/NLwkzmpV

Comment: Works if you also use the Project Explorer to delete the RemoteSystemsFiles
project and "remove from disk" AND you CD to Eclipse workspace (check
General.Startup and Shutdown preference, because there can be more than one
workspace active) and remove the "rse" jar file:

mv c:/eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.rse_3.5.0.201403100950.jar c:/save

Comment: THIS IS THE BEST. THING. EVER... I like eclipse, but eff me do they fill it up with junk these days or what...

Comment: the answer from bit2shift seems to be a lot cleaner / safer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972116/3375325

Comment: Yep, use the one above instead.  It worked great for me.

Comment: I had to also keep an eye on my workspace's folder which got a RemoteSystemsTempFiles project folder recreated a couple of times. Delete that and retry starting Eclipse with the -clean flag

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to remove the ***Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime*** package.
*Help* > *Installation Details* > *Installed Software* and scroll down until you see it.

It has several sub-packages, all of which are removed altogether with their parent package.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest / safest solution as it also updates the Eclipse configuration files correctly (removing RSE features etc.)

Comment: This is the correct answer, and precisely why developers are moving away from Eclipse in droves...Garbage files right in my workspace!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that there might be situations in which you actually do not have the **RSE UI plug-ins** installed. However, the **RemoteSystemTempFiles** will still appear in your search results :-(

**Example**: For instance you have used an earlier version of Eclipse, including the RSE UI plug-ins. Later you have installed a newer version, probably to a different folder, but reusing the old workspace (via conversion). This time you have not installed the RSE UI plug-ins so your IDE has no option about this damn thing (which in fact is a very nice tool while working on Remote Systems).

However, despite the fact it doesn't have the plug-ins installed, Eclipse will still update/use that old/existent RemoteSystemTempFiles repository/container/whatever and thus it will always appear in your Search Results. **Pretty annoying, I know!**

**The solution** is quite simple:

1. In only 2 steps: install the plug-in then disable it.

   - select `Help` -> `Install New Software`, then choose the "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/[your-version-here]", then enter `remote` in the filter box.
   - search for the `Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime` & co. Probably the plug-ins could be found within the `General Purpose Tools` group, but this group may change from one edition/platform to other
   - install it/them then restart your IDE.
2. After it reopens select `Window` -> `Preferences` then select the `General` -> `Startup and Shutdown` and uncheck the `RSE UI`. Now it is disabled even in Search Results. Additionally you may select `Window` -> `Preferences` then `Remote Systems` -> `File Cache` and click `Clear Cached Files`.

**That would do the trick** - hopefully ;-)

Comment: Doesn't work when the downloadable version is behind the version already installed

Comment: Does not work on version 2021-03 (4.19.0)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using the Javascript perspective.  By default on the left side it has a 'Script Explorer' instead of a 'Project Explorer'.  It seems it was by default showing the files in the workspace instead of just the projects.  I imagine it is the same with the PHP perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using PHP Explorer perspective. I always had the problem that Eclipse could not save project metadata. I selected the "filters" to uncheck RSE Temporary Project. Once it appeared in the tree view, I right click to delete it.
Then I can check again to keep same initial config.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I find it quite useful during development, especially if I'm working on a project that has configurations, templates and properties files that are located outside of my project and I have no intention to include them in the package.
if you open the `.project` of `RemoteSystemsTempFiles` you can link a couple of external folders that you might want to work on and not ship or version.(look at the link tag)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>RemoteSystemsTempFiles</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.rse.ui.remoteSystemsTempNature</nature>
    </natures>
    <linkedResources>
        <link>
            <name>CONFIG</name>
            <type>2</type>
            <location>C:/CONFIG</location>
        </link>
    </linkedResources>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to get rid of these files is remove them physically....
go to ../../eclipse-workspace/RemoteSystemsTempFiles and remove from there..

Comment: This answer adds no additional value regarding other already given answers.

Comment: Problem with above comments are to do with eclipse, we need to remove physically which no one tells as of I observed . thanks.

Comment: The problem with your answer is not mentioning that if **Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime** is installed, that same project will be recreated every time Eclipse is started. Fight the cause, not the consequences!