# Is there any way to completely remove or disable the "Remote Search" option in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I find it very annoying every time I go to perform a search and I click on remote search by accident without even realising it.

I have already tried disabling all of the options under window->preferences relating to remote systems, including disabling the RSE plugin from the startup settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470979/588476

> from eclipse\plugins folder remove all the (org.eclipse.rse.*.jar) files

Works for me!